# Optimality proof for the coin-change problem of 1, 2, 5 and 10

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, alternative-proof

I have four types of coins: 1, 2, 5 and 10. When I am given a number $k \in \mathbb{N}^{+}$, I have to return the least number of coins to reach that number. Using a greedy algorithm I can simply return all the possible 10 coins, and from the remaining, all possible 5 coins, and so on.

I need to proof that this greedy algorithm always return an optimal solution.

After some research, I realized this problem is called the coin-change problem and those coin systems that always return optimal solutions are called "canonical coin systems". Characterization of canonical coin systems has been made partially using theorems over specific subsets ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3122291/722100), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1209657/722100), [3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.0400.pdf)), but these theorems seems pretty hard to prove. Is there any simpler proof that I can use for this specific case of 1, 2, 5 and 10 without using those theorems?

For instance, the coinset 1, 5 and 10 can be easily proved to be canonical because every element is a factor of the larger elements. Can I use something similar in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know the proof as to why $S = \{1, 5, 10\}$ is canonical, then you can easily prove that $S' = \{1, 2, 5, 10\}$ is canonical. This is clearly true since, if $x$ never equals $2, 3,$ or $4$, then we never exercise our option to take the coin $2$, and we obtain an optimal solution due to the optimality of $S$. Conversely, if $x$ equals $2, 3,$ or $4$ at some point, then we can *only do better* by taking fewer coins since all of these cases reduce directly to either $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 2):

The greedy algorithm here is optimal. Obviously, if there are two $5$ coins, then this is sub-optimal by replacing with $10$. Similarly, one should replace two $1$s with a $2$, and replace three $2$s with one $5$ and one $1$. Hence there is at most one $1$, at most two $2$s, and at most one $5$. Furthermore, if there are two $2$s and one $1$, then this is sub-optimal by replacing with $5$.

It can be seen that these values are the ones given by the greedy algorithm.